# Spark Structured Streaming groupby window - I want first interval start on the first time stamp

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming

From a simple complete example of using window aggregation on Spark 2.31 (HDP 3.0), I can see that Spark creates intervals that are aligned to some whole number. For example, here I specify 60 seconds windowDuration, and Spark starts the first interval on the nearest minute:

```
>>> from pyspark.sql import functions as F
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame([("2016-03-11 09:00:07", 1),("2016-03-11 09:00:08", 1)]).toDF("date", "val")
>>> w = df.groupBy(F.window("date", "60 seconds")).agg(F.sum("val").alias("sum"))
>>> w.select(w.window.start.cast("string").alias("start"),w.window.end.cast("string").alias("end"), "sum").collect()
[Row(start='2016-03-11 09:00:00', end='2016-03-11 09:01:00', sum=2)]
```

Is there a way to start interval at the first message, i.e. in my case I'd like to have:

`[Row(start='2016-03-11 09:00:07', end='2016-03-11 09:01:07', sum=2)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go =>

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from datetime import datetime

df = spark.createDataFrame([("2016-03-11 09:00:07", 1),("2016-03-11 09:00:08", 1)]).toDF("date", "val")

startSecond = datetime.strptime(df.head()[0], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').second

w = df.groupBy(F.window("date", "60 seconds", "60 seconds", str(startSecond) + " seconds")).agg(F.sum("val").alias("sum"))

w.select(w.window.start.cast("string").alias("start"),w.window.end.cast("string").alias("end"), "sum").collect()
```

Comment: Thanks! Reading the docs I had a thought that it might work this way, but tried wrong things

Comment: The only thing here is how to get startSecond in Streaming mode:     `startSecond = datetime.strptime(st.head()[0], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').second
 ...
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: 'Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start();;\nkafka'`